# w3m: fake JavaScript and user-agent

Tags: shell, w3m

I use w3m to search words in the Spanish dictionary (`dle.rae.es`), so I'm using a bash script with this line:

```sh
w3m "https://dle.rae.es/$1"
```

The filename of the script is `defes`. For example, to search the meaning of "casa" I type `defes casa`, viewing the result in my terminal.

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Please enable cookies.

Please wait...

We are checking your browser... dle.rae.es

Please stand by, while we are checking your browser...

Redirecting...

Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.

Please enable Cookies and reload the page.

Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?

Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.

What can I do to prevent this in the future?

If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not
infected with malware.

If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking
for misconfigured or infected devices.

Cloudflare Ray ID: 69ffcac51e4a668f • Your IP: XX.YYY.ZZZ.NNN • Performance & security by Cloudflare
```

I try to do something like this:

```sh
w3m -header 'User-Agent: blah' ...
```

Tested with a lot user agents.

I'm also using the `-cookie` flag to try to remove the cookies message...

What could I do?